# What are the Boeing 777 aural alerts indicating in this ATC recording?

Tags: boeing-777, cockpit-alerts

There was a [recent incident](https://avherald.com/h?article=4f700fec) (avherald.com) with an Air France Boeing 777 on approach to CDG where several different aural warnings can be heard in the [ATC audio recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzCNKhFOPqU&t=29s) (YouTube) when the pilot has the mic keyed. They went around and ultimately landed safely, but I'm just curious what all of the different aural warnings that can be heard in the recording in the linked video indicate.

Note: I am specifically ***not*** asking for speculation about the cause(s) of the incident. That is [explicitly off-topic here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I'm only asking what the different aural alerts that can be heard are designed to indicate.

Comment: A video about the incident made by a 777 pilot. He comments on the audio recording from about 8 minute mark. https://youtu.be/cslSQB5mgyc (also explains the procedures and mentions a couple of possible reasons for the problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only hear 2 distinct warning sounds in the video:

1. There is a high-low tone audible from 0:31 to 0:35 (also heard later). This is the **master warning siren**.
2. There is a low-to-high sound audible from 0:48 to 0:50 (also again around 0:57). This is the **autopilot disconnect wailer**.

My 777 FCOM groups both of these sounds in the same category (under siren):

> | Aural | Light | Calls Attention To |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Siren | Master WARNING lights | EICAS Warning Message: |
> |  |  | AUTOPILOT DISC |
> |  |  | CONFIG DOORS |
> |  |  | CONFIG FLAPS |
> |  |  | CONFIG GEAR STEERING |
> |  |  | CONFIG PARKING BRAKE |
> |  |  | CONFIG RUDDER |
> |  |  | CONFIG SPOILERS |
> |  |  | CONFIG STABILIZER |
> |  |  | OVERSPEED |
> |  |  | CAIN ALTITUDE |
> |  |  | PILOT RESPONSE |
> |  |  | STABILIZER |
> | Beeper | Master CAUTION lights | New EICAS caution message, except: |
> |  |  | ENG SHUTDOWN |
> |  |  | ENG SHUTDOWN L |
> |  |  | ENG SHUTDOWN R |

<sup>(Boeing 777 FCOMv2 15.20.5 - Warning Systems - System Description)</sup>

There are however *company options* available to play the wailer instead of the siren for autopilot disconnect, meaning some airlines get different aural alerts.

I cannot hear the **master caution beeper** in the video.

References for all sounds (YouTube links are timestamped):

- Master Warning Siren: [YouTube](https://youtu.be/eotXGqBJlSA?t=46) (0:46 - 0:49), example of PILOT RESPONSE in-flight (thanks @ymb1): [YouTube](https://youtu.be/tyn_Ik7x8OE?t=2595) (43:21 - 43:30)
- Autpilot Disconnect Wailer: [YouTube](https://youtu.be/9i2tmlZ509c?t=7) (0:07 - 0:09)
- Master Caution Beeper: [YouTube](https://youtu.be/9i2tmlZ509c?t=4) (0:04 - 0:05)

Comment: The third sound I was referring to is a high-pitched chirp that I can hear at least a couple of times in the background behind the pilot breathing in between the Master Warning and the AP disconnect. If you start listening around [0:50](https://youtu.be/VzCNKhFOPqU?t=50), there's what sounds like a chirp right around 0:54 and again at 0:56 before the AP disconnect sounds again.

Comment: @reirab OK, I just listened to that part again. I think I know what chirp you mean, but I'm not familiar with it as an aural alert in the 777. It might be something partially cut-off by the transmission or even an artifact of poor AM radio quality. Not sure though...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like the beeper which indicates a Caution message on the EICAS. That could be any of a large number of conditions.

A Warning message from EICAS is accompanied by a siren, and it didn't sound like one to me, but even that could be any of a number of conditions.

Comment: If you play the video at 50% you will hear the beeper as well as a hi-lo tone. I thought at first it was the master caution warning, but I don't have the 777 manuals with me to confirm.

Comment: @Raffles There seem to be at least 3 different tone patterns in the video. There's at least a high-low, a high-pitched chirp, and a repeated low-to-high ramp-up (latter is AP disconnect, maybe?)

Comment: The Caution beeper sounds like [this](https://youtu.be/9i2tmlZ509c?t=4).

Answer (score 0):

The Hi-Lo tone is the Auto Pilot disconnect aural warning. I can't identify the other coming later in the vidéo.